# how to cluster colors in a single image?

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing

I have some experience in `Opencv`.
I want to cluster colors of an image.

For example if I cluster the below image:

**i should get 6 clusters each having a cluster name as their RGB value along with their postion(x,y)**

[image: world continent]

Is there a way to do this using `Opencv` or any opensource packages is also ok.
I am comfortable with Java and C.
If you want more details post your comments.

Comment: what do you expect to get? an iplimage for each color/cluster? how complex should the solution be? should "shades of red" be in the same cluster or should it cluster by the exact rgb value? ie: in the image provided you have 9 clusters... red, green, yellow, blue, violet, vomit (no better name for this color :) ) and 3 connected components of the black outline.

Comment: @Boaz.Jan i just want the output like 6 (x,y) cordinates. each one of (x,y) point in the center of each cluster (ie) each continent

Answer (score 0):

For this particular image (which has 6 cluster, with each color). I mean there is doesn't exist two cluster with same color. I think we just need to find the centerpoint.

1) We can use Point to store the position of pixel. new Point(width, height).

2) Then we need to determine, which pixels in which color. By iterate through all pixel, we can also get the number of color/cluster.

3) For each color/cluster we need to calculate the centerpoint, by calculate the mean for all pixel/point that have that color.